# Could not install PyCurl 7.43.0.6 on Python 3.8.8 | RHEL 8.3

Tags: python, pycurl, rhel8

Workstation details:

- RHEL 8.3 - x86_64
- Python 3.8.8
- libcurl 7.61.1-14.el8_3.1

I tried

> pip install pycurl==7.43.0.6

The error [traceback]:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/raa/Projects/venv/test55/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-s049piq0/pycurl_e1573e1fea9a47e5a16d1e71517e3013/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-s049piq0/pycurl_e1573e1fea9a47e5a16d1e71517e3013/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-46mx471v
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-s049piq0/pycurl_e1573e1fea9a47e5a16d1e71517e3013/
Complete output (22 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pip-install-s049piq0/pycurl_e1573e1fea9a47e5a16d1e71517e3013/setup.py", line 236, in configure_unix
    p = subprocess.Popen((self.curl_config(), '--version'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1706, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-s049piq0/pycurl_e1573e1fea9a47e5a16d1e71517e3013/setup.py", line 988, in <module>
    ext = get_extension(sys.argv, split_extension_source=split_extension_source)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-s049piq0/pycurl_e1573e1fea9a47e5a16d1e71517e3013/setup.py", line 649, in get_extension
    ext_config = ExtensionConfiguration(argv)
  File "/tmp/pip-install-s049piq0/pycurl_e1573e1fea9a47e5a16d1e71517e3013/setup.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.configure()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-s049piq0/pycurl_e1573e1fea9a47e5a16d1e71517e3013/setup.py", line 241, in configure_unix
    raise ConfigurationError(msg)
__main__.ConfigurationError: Could not run curl-config: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl-config'
----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/1a/35b1d8b8e4e23a234f1b17a8a40299fd550940b16866c9a1f2d47a04b969/pycurl-7.43.0.6.tar.gz#sha256=8301518689daefa53726b59ded6b48f33751c383cf987b0ccfbbc4ed40281325 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pycurl/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycurl==7.43.0.6
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycurl==7.43.0.6
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the error is not related to Python or the package pycurl. It was due to the missing `libcurl-devel` on RHEL.

The error message/trackback did not mention this clearly.

In RHEL 8, I installed the library using `sudo dnf install libcurl-devel`.

Later, `pip install pycurl==7.43.0.6` solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me (CentOS 7 and Python 3.6)